# how can I achieve such layout with Android SDK?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android development and after few years of strict c++ coding with apis such as ogl, dx, sfml i really got a headache with all those layouts and stuff.

Basically i'm asking you how to achieve the following setup:

[image]

I tried putting together some random layouts and fixing it up with WYSIWYG editor but this thing just drives me bananas and i cant make it work. It feels like whatever I do, the editor behaves differently.

If someone could give me some tips it would be awesome.

BTW, can i create an event in form [`Activity` in this case] that is called each frame? [no game loop sucks!]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to break everything down into layouts within one another. Here would be an example of what you need but there are many many ways to define the exact same thing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" 
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! Figured it out with your help. Looks like I gotta type margins and sizes manually cuz their editor simply blows... BTW: loving this community giving minus points on my thread <3

Comment: Ya the drag and drop idea is great but is very frustrating to actually use. I generally drop a few items onto the screen and then completely redo the screen from the code side. Linear layouts can be very limiting but the relative layout adds a ton of customization. Try typing "android:" inside a layout then let it sit for a min and thumb through the list that comes up and you can see all the possibilities relative layouts add. If your using eclipse that is i don't know about other editors.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a LinearLayout with vertical orientation. Your imageview+textview could itself be a LinearLayout with vertical orientation.

Read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

Comment: Yeah but I cant seem to resize imageview to whatever size I want. 
And I want textview to overlap with imageview.